# Token is Invalid in Reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I try to get a list from the backend in Reactjs component with JWT token but I get an error message **{"status":"Token is Invalid"}**, please guide me.

My backend API is working fine and my token is saved in the localstore after login.

**my frontend used API code**

```
import {API} from "../config";
/**
*  to get about pages
*  get a single about page
*  update a about page
*  delete about page
*/
export const getAboutContent = (token) =>{
return fetch(`${API}/about/?token=${token}`, {
    method: "GET",
 })
.then(response =>{
    return response.json();      
 })
 .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
 });
 };
```

**about/index.js**

```
const [allAboutContent, setAllAboutContent] = useState([]);

const loadAllAboutContent = () => {
  getAboutContent().then(data => {
        if(data.error){
            console.log(data.error)
        } else{
          setAllAboutContent(data.data)
        }
    });
};

useEffect(() =>{
  loadAllAboutContent();
}, [])
```

[image: API Image]

[image: My Component Page]

[image: LocalStorage Saved token]

Please help.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the URL you're requesting has `?token=undefined`, so the token you're passing to `getAboutContent` is `undefined`. So, how do you call `getAboutContent`? The issue is almost certainly when you call that function.

Comment: @Nick thanks for your reply, please tell me how to fix this issue..Please guide me

Comment: Can you add the code where you actually call the `getAboutContent` function?

Comment: @Nick sir, please check I post my code...

Comment: maybe u should check which part of your backend code is throwing the error

Comment: my API is working fine I check, I also try to get data without a token and it's working fine but I need to do this with a token...I remove  my API route from middleware and  pass it in frontend code then it's work but I don't want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `getAboutContent` in `about/index.js` file without JWT and hence it not defined. Just update your code to read JWT from localStorage like below

```
const loadAllAboutContent = () => {
  // Read token from local storage
  const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
  // Pass to getAboutContent
  getAboutContent(token).then(data => {
    if(data.error){
        console.log(data.error)
    } else{
      setAllAboutContent(data.data)
    }
  });
};
```

Also, I see you have stored your token as `{token: ''}`. Maybe, you can directly save it. Otherwise you have to read it like this `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt')).token`